# Sum Fields in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-expression

I have two cloumns in ssrs

**1. Column10**

Expression(column1 + column2 + column 3)

**2. Column11**

Expression(column4 + column5 + column 6)

Now I want to **subtract** column 11 from column 10

I am doing now

```
 =(Fields!column1.Value) + (Fields!column2.Value) + 
 (Fields!column3.Value) 
 - 
 (Fields!column4.Value) + (Fields!column5.Value) + 
 (Fields!column6.Value)
```

Is there any wrong with this approach. Any other better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression is incorrect. It is only subtracting Columnr4 - you need to use parenthesis around the entire part that is being subtracted.

```
 =(Fields!column1.Value + Fields!column2.Value + Fields!column3.Value) 
  - 
  (Fields!column4.Value + Fields!column5.Value + Fields!column6.Value)
```

I try to use as few parenthesis as possible to avoid errors like this.

I don't like using Report Items. You could create two calculated fields in the dataset - one for the Column 10 and one for Column 11 that has the expression for each.

Column 10:

```
=(Fields!column1.Value + Fields!column2.Value + Fields!column3.Value)
```

Column 11:

```
=(Fields!column4.Value + Fields!column5.Value + Fields!column6.Value)
```

[image]

Then your expression for Column 12 would be

```
=Fields!column10.Value - Fields!column11.Value
```

Answer (score 1):

`=Me.ReportItems("txtColumn11").Value - Me.ReportItems("txtColumn10").Value`

In the double quotes, is the name of the textbox.

When it's possible, I prefer doing most calculations in the query so there is less business logic in the report expressions.